# Duplicated root when serializing

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am trying to serialize a dictionary into xml, but the structure of the xml is different to the one I would like. For some reason instead of having one root and multiple child within that root I get a new root for each key and value in the dictionary. Also the message box is being shown for each KeyValuePair within the dictionary, I would like the message box to be shown once when the dictionaries were exported. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 with C# and all values within the dictionary collected from text boxes on a windows form.

This is how the current xml layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Coordinate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Date_Time>10/02/2015 11/17/00</Date_Time>
   <BeaconID>1</BeaconID>
   <X_Coordinate>2</X_Coordinate>
   <Y_Coordinate>3</Y_Coordinate>
</Coordinate><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Coordinate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Date_Time>10/02/2015 11/17/01</Date_Time>
   <BeaconID>2</BeaconID>
   <X_Coordinate>3</X_Coordinate>
   <Y_Coordinate>4</Y_Coordinate>
</Coordinate>
```

And this is how I would like it to look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Coordinates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Coordinate>
        <Date_Time>10/02/2015 11/17/00</Date_Time>
        <BeaconID>1</BeaconID>
        <X_Coordinate>2</X_Coordinate>
        <Y_Coordinate>3</Y_Coordinate>
    </Coordinate>
    <Coordinate>
        <Date_Time>10/02/2015 11/17/01</Date_Time>
        <BeaconID>2</BeaconID>
        <X_Coordinate>3</X_Coordinate>
        <Y_Coordinate>4</Y_Coordinate>
     </Coordinate>
</Coordinates>
```

This is all of my xml related code:

```
public void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>> entry in d)
        {
            Coordinate v = new Coordinate();

            v.Date_Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh/mm/ss");
            v.BeaconID = entry.Key;
            v.X_Coordinate = entry.Value.Item1.ToString();
            v.Y_Coordinate = entry.Value.Item2.ToString();

            SaveValues(v);
        }
    }

    public class Coordinate//Root element
    {
        public string Date_Time { get; set; }
        public string BeaconID { get; set; }
        public string X_Coordinate { get; set; }
        public string Y_Coordinate { get; set; }
    }

    public void SaveValues(Coordinate v)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Coordinate));
        using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"F:\Vista\Exporting into XML\Test1\Coordinates output.xml", true))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, v);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Coordinates were exported successfully", "Message");//Let the user know the export was succesfull            
    }
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong. If I am missing anything or I just wasn't clear enough just let me know it and I will help with it. I am new to XML and to serialization so any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

@P.K. A better explanation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Coordinates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Coordinate>
    <Coordinate>
      <DateTime>10/02/2015 02/35/14</DateTime>
      <BeaconID>1</BeaconID>
      <XCoordinate>2</XCoordinate>
      <YCoordinate>3</YCoordinate>
    </Coordinate>
    <Coordinate>
      <DateTime>10/02/2015 02/35/14</DateTime>
      <BeaconID>2</BeaconID>
      <XCoordinate>3</XCoordinate>
      <YCoordinate>4</YCoordinate>
    </Coordinate>
  </Coordinate>
</Coordinates>
```

Instead of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Coordinates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Coordinate>
      <DateTime>10/02/2015 02/35/14</DateTime>
      <BeaconID>1</BeaconID>
      <XCoordinate>2</XCoordinate>
      <YCoordinate>3</YCoordinate>
    </Coordinate>
    <Coordinate>
      <DateTime>10/02/2015 02/35/14</DateTime>
      <BeaconID>2</BeaconID>
      <XCoordinate>3</XCoordinate>
      <YCoordinate>4</YCoordinate>
    </Coordinate>
</Coordinates>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try below code?

```
public void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>>> d = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>>("1",Tuple.Create<int,int>(1,1)),
                new KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>>("2",Tuple.Create<int,int>(2,2)),
                new KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>>("3",Tuple.Create<int,int>(3,3)),
                new KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>>("4",Tuple.Create<int,int>(4,4)),
                new KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>>("5",Tuple.Create<int,int>(5,5))
            };

            List<Coordinate> cv = new List<Coordinate>();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>> entry in d)
            {
                Coordinate v = new Coordinate();

                v.Date_Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh/mm/ss");
                v.BeaconID = entry.Key;
                v.X_Coordinate = entry.Value.Item1.ToString();
                v.Y_Coordinate = entry.Value.Item2.ToString();
                cv.Add(v);
            }
            SaveValues(cv);
        }

    public void SaveValues(List<Coordinate> v)
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Coordinate>), new XmlRootAttribute("Coordinates"));
                using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"F:\Vista\Exporting into XML\Test1\Coordinates output.xml", true))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, v);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Coordinates were exported successfully", "Message");//Let the user know the export was succesfull            
            }
```

Updated code to have dictionary...

```
public void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>> d = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>>();
            int X_Co = 1;
            int Y_Co = 1;
            var t = new Tuple<int, int>(X_Co, Y_Co);
            d.Add("1", t);

            X_Co = 2;
            Y_Co = 2;
            t = new Tuple<int, int>(X_Co, Y_Co);
            d.Add("2", t);

                List<Coordinate> cv = new List<Coordinate>();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>> entry in d)
                {
                    Coordinate v = new Coordinate();

                    v.Date_Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh/mm/ss");
                    v.BeaconID = entry.Key;
                    v.X_Coordinate = entry.Value.Item1.ToString();
                    v.Y_Coordinate = entry.Value.Item2.ToString();
                    cv.Add(v);
                }
                SaveValues(cv);
            }
```

Updated code to have separate files for every loop.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>> entry in d)
            {
                List<Coordinate> cv = new List<Coordinate>();
                Coordinate v = new Coordinate();

                v.Date_Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh/mm/ss");
                v.BeaconID = entry.Key;
                v.X_Coordinate = entry.Value.Item1.ToString();
                v.Y_Coordinate = entry.Value.Item2.ToString();
                cv.Add(v);
                SaveValues(cv);
            }
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works, but could you help with editing your list to use my tuple which uses two ints X_Co and Y_Co? Here is my tuple: var t = new Tuple<int, int>(X_Co, Y_Co);

Comment: My tuple is also using multiple int parameters.

Comment: Could you send your code snippet of keyvaluepair parmeter?

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier I was not PC nearby. What exactly you mean by keyvaluepair parameter, is it my dictionary and/or tuple?

Comment: In your code, you have "foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>> entry in d)"

Where and How do you set "d" ?

Comment: "Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>> d = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<int, int>>();"           is my dictionary within the form    "public partial class Form2 : Form"         and I add the values on "btn_Add_Click" event using this code   "d.Add(B_ID, t);" tuple is also created within the button click  "var t = new Tuple<int, int>(X_Co, Y_Co);" I can put every code in the question if that helps.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated comment. This code using Dictionary which you have mentioned. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Works like a charm, I had to remove the line where you create the dictionary as I had mine created at the top of the code. Thank you. Just one more question, it is optional but could you help how to create a separate xml file every time a list of coordinates is exported within a specific folder and the file name would be the today's date maybe.

Comment: Please update your foreach code with my updated snippet and let me know if in case.. :)
Dont forget to update XML file-name to have different file name every time.

Comment: I updated my code but I can't seem to figure out how to change the path so that each file would have a unique name and located in a specific folder.

Comment: Please update the TextWriter with following,  using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"F:\Vista\Exporting into XML\Test1\Coordinates output" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".xml", true))

and let me know

Comment: Found a problem, the message box shows up for each of the coordinates instead of once, can you help with that too? Also changed the date format to + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss") + just so it is more readable

Comment: You an remove the messagebox from SetValue method and add the messagebox after foreach statements closing braket.

 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>> entry in d)
{
  //// your existing code.
}
MessageBox.Show("Coordinates were exported successfully", "Message");

Answer (score 0):

1. "Also the message box is being shown for each KeyValuePair within the dictionary"
   It is caused due to calling SaveValues(v); inside the 'for' loop.

2.
SaveValues should save a list of coordinates (List ). 
By running it against each coordinate causing it to generate distinct XML document each time , appending it to the document .

3. In order to control the name of generated XML elements , use XmlAttributes on the 
   Coordinate object .

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
For furtehr info

Side note : 
I recommend using consistent property naming : 
either 'BeaconID' Upper camel case
Or 'X_Coordinate' upper snake case (?)
It makes the code easier to read.

**EDIT**

```
The name 'v' does not exist in the current context
```

means that the variable named 'v' is not defined in this scope. 
The reason you are having this error is because you are trying to use the variable 'v' before declaring it (Coordinate v). 
I recommend getting familiar with the basics of the C# language , for further info .

A very good resource is

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you for answering, I tried calling SaveValues(v) outside the loop but it gave me the error "The name 'v' does not exist in the current context ". I am not sure what you mean by the second point, sorry English isn't my first language. I tried using XmlAttributes but I am not sure where exactly and which one should I use from the website you linked, could you maybe tailor the right attribute to the layout I would like to achieve if its not much to ask. Thank you

Comment: The name 'v' does not exist in the current context  means that the variable named 'v' is not defined in this scope.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain the second point in more detail? I learnt C# in college but only for a year so there wasn't enough time to learn more than the basics.

Comment: Sure , see ,the code in btn_Submit_Click runs in a loop on every element of the dictionary 'd' , convert each dictionary entry to a Coordinate object and **for each ** coordinate objects , create a separate XML file .  What is suggested is create a new variable of type List of Coordinates like this : List<Coordinate> myList=new List<Coordinate>(); Then instead of creating an XML add the coordinate object to the new list , after the dictionary loop ends  call SaveValues with myList as its input. of course change the setValue method to accept List<Coordinate> . Also see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing for you will be to add another class as Coordinates. Store all the child nodes inside this object before finally flushing it out.

```
public class Coordinates
{
    public Coordinate[] Coordinate;
}

public void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Coordinate> lstCoordinates = new List<Coordinate>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<int, int>> entry in d)
    {
        Coordinate v = new Coordinate();

        v.Date_Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh/mm/ss");
        v.BeaconID = entry.Key;
        v.X_Coordinate = entry.Value.Item1.ToString();
        v.Y_Coordinate = entry.Value.Item2.ToString();

        lstCoordinates.Add(v);
    }

    Coordinates cdCol = new Coordinates();
    cdCol.Coordinate = lstCoordinates.ToArray();
    SaveValues(cdCol);
}

public void SaveValues(Coordinates v)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Coordinates));
    using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"F:\Vista\Exporting into XML\Test1\Coordinates output.xml", true))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, v);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Coordinates were exported successfully", "Message");//Let the user know the export was succesfull            
}
```

Comment: I gave a try to your code gave me two different errors:
1 The type or namespace name 'Coordinate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


2 'Test1.Form2.Coordinates.Coordinate' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: @BenjáminAranyi Have you deleted the class `Coordinate' ? Because it should be there.

Comment: My fault I didn't realise public class Coordinates was a new class so I just renamed mine. It works now but it requires a little change as the xml is Coordinates>Coordinate> All coordinates are here instead of Coordinates> All coordinates are here

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the results you are is that *you're just appending a new XML document to the file*.  `StreamWriter` just writes whatever you tell it to - it does not know that data already exists in XML format and you need to merge the new XML with the existing data.

If you want to *fully* export the collection as valid XML, you need to create the collection in memory, then write that out as a *new* file (not appending to an existing one).  If that means that you need to read in the existing XML than that may be what you have to do.